# updateSearchResultsForSearchController not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c

My viewcontroller .h as below

```
@interface DiaryViewController : BaseViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating>
```

My viewcontroller.m as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //for search
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
//
//    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    [self searchForText:searchString scope:searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)searchForText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSInteger)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"diaryText like %@",
                                    searchText];

    self.searchResults = [self.diaryInfoArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    // you forget to reload Data
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    // else use

    //[yourtableView reloadData];

}
```

I am trying to implement search function inside a view controller which contains tableview. I found out that `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` is not being called despite the proper declarations at viewDidLoad. Any solution to this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this searchController IBOutlet connection ?

Comment: no its not. now I am able to get the results in searchResults. but how do I display it in tableview ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?